# What are the intervals $I$ for which the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges in norm $L^1 (I)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

For n=1,2,... let $f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f_n(x)= {\sqrt[3]{n-x} \over {e}^{(x-n)^2}}$$

Determine to what intervals of the real axis $I$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges in norm $L^1 (I)$

My work:

$\int_a^b |\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)-\sum_{n=k-1}^{\infty}f_n(x)|dx=\int_a^b |\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}f_n(x)| dx \le \int_a^b \sum_{n=k}^{\infty}{\sqrt[3]{|n-x|} \over {e}^{(x-n)^2}} dx $ $\le \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \int_{a-n}^{b-n} {\sqrt[3]{|y|} \over {e}^{y^2}} dy=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_n$

if $b \neq +\infty$ :$a_n \le \int_{a-n}^{b-n} {-y \over e^{y^2} }dy= - {1\over2}[-e^{-(b-n)^2}+e^{-(a-n)^2}]$

Therefore $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}a_n$ coverges and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges in norm $L^1 ((-\infty,b))$  $  \forall b \in \mathbb{R}$

I think that if $b=+\infty$ and $a \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty\} $ the series diverges but I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Did you note that $f_n(x)=g(n-x)$ for some specific function $g$ and did you try to use this fact?

Comment: mmh sorry but i don't see how use your hint